# How do I get a JTable header to display entire column names instead of shortening them?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader, text-size

I've a JTable that I fill with a class that extends AbstractTableModel. The problem is that the columns are too short to display the column name. I've turned off Jtable AutoResizeMode property, but shortening still occurs. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting off autoresizemode only prevent the JTable's coumns to be resized. To force a particular width retrieve the table column model:

```
TableColumn column = jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(col_num);
```

and set the desired width:

```
column.setPreferredWidth(width);
```

Comment: that's only half of the solution: the other half is to find out what the "desired width" is ;) see Rob's answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) to adjust the column widths based on the header text.

The `getColumnHeaderWidth(...)` shows how to calculate the actual width using the header text and renderer.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways

1) calculate `PreferredSize` from `TableColumn` (by defalut returns JLabel), there are 3-4 correct ways how to determine displayed `TextLenght in pixex` (please add plus 5-8 pixes moreover)

2) `setPreferredSize` directly, e.g. `TableColumn#setPreferredSize`

Comment: randomly adding the one or other pixel or dollar or apple ;-) Have to admit, that SwingX' ColumnFactory does exactly the same, adding a magic "default margin"